# MSSQL. Почему nvarchar значение само конвертится в int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Это проект таблицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь добавить запись - ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему значения nvarchar само конвертится в int? Тип поля GroupName ведь nvarchar

Comment: эмм... так написано же, что оно само **не** «конвертится»...

Answer (score 3):

Если в выражении участвуют значения разных типов, MS SQL пытается неявно преобразовать их к одному общему типу. Матрицу возможных преобразований можно посмотреть, например, здесь:

[Data type conversion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

При этом иcпользуется [Data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) и тип будет преобразован к типу с более высоким precedence.

В Вашем случае тип `nvarchar` ниже чем `int`, поэтому после неявного преобразования возникает ошибка.